# How to use SANE to scan a document 1:1

Tags: sane

The simplest job in the world - scan a black-and-white legal document (US portrait size).  The only goal is that the scanned document is 1:1, meaning the same size and location on the page.

I'm using GIMP, XSane, and an LIDE 210 scanner.  If I choose "Letter Port." (meaning, I hope, US letter portrait) in the XSane preview window, the scanned document is smaller and offset to the right side.  If I choose "Full Size" and crop to US portrait size, the top line of the document is clipped.

Is there some combination of software that actually works?

(Along the way, I must admit that XSane is one of the flukiest interfaces I've recently come across - I love the the way previewing the document changes the scan size, gamma, brightness, and contrast...)

Answer (score 1):

I just use ['Simple Scan'](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/simple-scan/) - I think it is installed by default, and works very nicely *(and Simply)*. With some LIDE scanners, you have to set the DPI to circa 300 in the preferences, otherwise it will just won't scan - other than that, press the button, and it will just scan, and then you can save it.

If you leave the scanned image as it is, and don't crop it, then you can crop a copy of it in future if you need to.

Comment: Image is broken.